# Adding outlet from a switch

Tags: switch, receptacle, light

Please help me with the wiring.

I had two switches for 2 fixtures in the kitchen. I installed pot lights and now control them with switch 1. Wiring from switch 2 have been capped in the ceiling.

I want to convert switch 2 into an outlet. There's 14-3 coming in, with the black going to switch 2, white in bottom hot, red in top hot. Ground is screwed in the metal box. Then a small wire is connected from the side of bottom hot in 1 to bottom hot in 2.

Is it possible to get an outlet on this? Please dumb it down for me because I'm a beginner. And thank you so much in advance. [image]

[image]

Comment: An actual picture might provide additional information. Is there a second switch that controls the lights - i.e., switch 1 and another switch on another wall so that either switch can turn the lights on/off?

Comment: I think this might be a double-gang box and not two separate boxes. If so, then you may be able to do what you want, but would need to change some wiring for the 3-wire (make white a neutral and change the way the wires are connected). Pics would help.

Comment: Turn of the power to this switch at your circuit breaker panel, remove the cover plate(s) from the switches, remove the screws mounting the switches into the box, then, _WITHOUT_ removing any wires, pull the switches from the boxes. Then take clear, focused pics showing an over all view, showing the wiring on each switch, and the wiring from the switches into the back of the box so we can see how they run into cables at the back. Then, [edit] these pics into your question. Without that, our guess is as good as yours.

Comment: Pictures as asked will help a lot.  I do not think you have a neutral in that box, so adding an outlet will require more wiring.  It looks like an old style switch loop with two switch hots(long black and red).

Comment: Akhtar, a receptacle needs a neutral as well as a line hot,  but switches in general do not need a neutral. So to save cost in older wiring no neutral was provided in switch boxes. From your drawing one would conclude that the white wire is a line hot (always hot) from the light fixture. The short black wire is to carry the line hot to the other switch. The outgoing black and red wires are the switched hots to the lights. If you don't want to use one light, you MAY be allowed to repurpose one of the outgoing switched hots as a line hot and change the white wire from a line hot to a neutra

Comment: manassehkatz - no, there is only one switch in the kitchen to control the lights.

Comment: RG Hughes - yes its a double gang box

Comment: Jim Stewart - so you're saying I MAY be able to connect the white to the outlet as the neutral, Keep black as is. The light switch will get power from the red. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes. the red would be reconnected up in the ceiling box to serve as the line hot for BOTH the light switch and the new receptacle. The white would be reconnected in the ceiling box to serve as the neutral to the receptacle. I am almost certain you can do this. I wrote "may" just on the off chance that there is something that one of the experts here would kow that I don't.

Comment: Thanks Jim, you've been very helpful. One more question. What happens to the the black coming into the box?

Comment: In the picture it looks like the black wire on switch 1 is going to a screw on the opposite side from the white. Is that true? Or is it going to a backstab right next to the white?

Comment: its the backstab, not the other side. Just looks like that from the angle I took

Comment: Jim - can you look at the image here and let me know if Im on the right track https://ibb.co/Xzf0Ctx

Comment: That would work  AFIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A receptacle needs a neutral as well as a line hot, but switches in general do not need a neutral. To save cost in older wiring no neutral was provided in switch boxes. In the case of a single switch there is usually not enough wires to provide a neutral, but in your case you have a two-gang box with an extra wire so you should be able to put a receptacle in place of one of the switches.

From your drawing one would conclude that originally the white wire was a line hot (always hot) from the light fixture. (Usually white is for a neutral, but in older wiring it was allowed to use a white as a line hot to a switch. In that use the white was supposed to be marked on the end with black tape or sharpie but often this was neglected.) If you have a non-contact voltage tester, you could verify whether the white is a line hot, but if you don't have a tester you could proceed on the assumtion that it is. If white is line hot, then in the ceiling box it would be connected to the (black) line hot there.

The short black wire is to carry the line hot to the other switch. The outgoing black and red wires are the switched hots to the lights. If you don't want to use one light, you could repurpose one of the outgoing switched hots (red or black whichever went to the light no longer wanted) as the line hot to carry line hot to the remaining switch and to the new receptacle.

You would reconnect the white wire in the fixture box from a line hot to a neutral. There will be a neutral in the fixture box because the light needs a neutral. This would be a white wire in the same cable as the (black) line hot. Do you have any test equipment like a non-contact voltage tester or a plug in receptacle tester?

If you have two ceiling boxes, then the line hot and its neutral might possibly be in only one of the boxes but it might be in both boxes. Experts here could weigh in on how that might affect what you have to do to install this receptacle.